# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "se me olvidó" y "olvidé"?

Tags: reflexivos

¿Cuáles son las **diferencias semánticas** entre "se me olvidó" y "olvidé"?
Ejemplo:

> Se me olvidó mi teléfono.
>
> Olvidé mi teléfono.

Creo que cuando se usa el reflexivo, esto indica menos responsabilidad de parte del sujeto que realiza la acción.

Otro ejemplo:

> Se me perdieron las llaves de la casa.
>
> Perdí las llaves de la casa.

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/849/12

Comment: A leson on colloquial Argentinish ["Me invitó a dar un paseo,y lo pasamos ragio,porque me se coló toda la familia asi que en lugar de cargar sólo conmigo,tuvo que cargar con el cuerpo humano de mi amá,los cuerpo humano de los chicos y el cuerpo humano del perro"](http://www.encontrarse.com/notas/pvernota.php3?nnota=19554) by the unforgettable [Niní Marshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nin%C3%AD_Marshall)

Comment: “se me olvidó” que te “olvidé”, a mí, que nada se me olvida...

Comment: Dificil. Al menos en Cuba “se me olvidó” es mas "coloquial" que “olvidé”?

Comment: @qPCR4vir por ejemplo lo que acabas de decir. "A mi no se me olvida nada." es necesario utilizar el reflexivo.

Comment: @Alfredo Osorio .  hmmm..., cuidado, que yo no olvido nada!  ?? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer estás buscando una diferencia semántica del tipo cognitivo.

Como ya mencionaste, en numerosas ocasiones los individuos usamos e interpretamos la diferencia como una cualidad que cae en la "responsabilidad moral" que una persona asume sobre la acción o el evento narrado; ya que la palabra "se", es normalmente utilizada para hacer una construcción pre-nominal de tercera persona, por ejemplo:

> Se saltó la barda. Se metió a la casa.

Sin embargo, desde una perspectiva psicológica se vuelve reflexivo, precisamente porque reflexionar sobre las propias acciones requiere de un mecanismo cognitivo de "exteriorización" u observación hacia uno mismo desde una perspectiva de 3ra persona.

Te subiero leer teoría sobre las distintas capas de conciencia que construyen la identidad.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.